# SIP soft phone in java

Tags: java, sip

I am looking for the best open source softphone that is implemented in JAVA and comes in a jar file.

Any suggestions?

Comment: No, just to invoke from the command line.

Comment: Why does it have to be implemented in java?

Comment: because the wrapper software can invoke java classes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No idea if it is best or not, but there is an applet http://www-x.antd.nist.gov/proj/iptel/  (look to JAIN-SIP-APPLET-PHONE).

Also, our company has used that sip stack implementation for own soft-phone

Answer (score 1):

Would this work for you: http://sip-communicator.org/

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean such thing as: [The free Java library for Asterisk PBX integration](http://blogs.reucon.com/asterisk-java/) ?

Answer (score 1):

I agree that SIP communicator is the best java softphone. It's the best because it's the only java sip softphone at the market. Don't search further.

Answer (score 1):

There's also http://peers.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 1):

Revosip java sip client uses single jar file http://revosip.com.